Limit of two index sequence
If $(u_{n,k})$ is a two index sequence such that $u_{n,k}=-u_{k,n}$ $\forall n,k$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} u_{n,k} =u$, can I exchange limits on $n$ and $k$ to get that $u=-u$, thus $u=0$ ?

The answer is negative as proven by the following counterexample:
$$u_{n,k} = \frac{n-k}{n+k}.$$

Indeed ! Thanks.
